# How to delete an item from a collection that is data bound to a GridView

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, webforms

Hi guys I am creating a simple website using the language of VB.NET, I am having trouble with one part at the moment and could really use some help.

At the moment I have items that are stored in a database, when the homepage loads these items are added to a Gridview which allows the user to select the items they wish to add to their shopping cart. Once an item is selected from the gridview it is added to a collection. That collection is then added to a Session. This is the code I have for completing that task.

```
  Public Function addToCollection() As Collection
    If Session("Order") Is Nothing Then
        colOrder = New Collection
        Session("Order") = colOrder
    Else
        colOrder = Session("Order")
    End If
    Return colOrder
End Function
```

Then this code will fill the session with the collection of items

```
    addToCollection()
    Dim gvRow As GridViewRow = gvCDs.SelectedRow
    Dim objOrder As Order = New Order
    objOrder.ID = gvRow.Cells(1).Text
    objOrder.Title = gvRow.Cells(2).Text
    objOrder.Artist = gvRow.Cells(3).Text
    objOrder.Price = gvRow.Cells(5).Text
    colOrder.Add(objOrder)

    Session("Order") = colOrder
```

Now on a new page I will display what items the user has stored in the Session by putting all the items in the session into a Gridview, This is the code for doing that

```
  gvOrder.DataSource = Session("Order")
  gvOrder.DataBind()
```

Now this is the part where I am stuck on and need someone to help me out, I want the user to be able to select a row in the gridview by using the gridviews build in selected toll and then they can click a button that will delete that item from the session and gridview.

Please can someone help me out with this.
Thanks 
Tim

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a column with CommandName = "Delete", then handle the RowDeleting event.  This is the body of that event handler.  I've added extra steps to make it more clear what's going on.

```
Dim orders as Collection = DirectCast(Session("Order"), Collection)
orders.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help but you cant remove ord from orders because the remove needs different arguments such as a index?

Comment: I have edited my answer to do an index-based removal.  I do not know what Collection class you are using, though, so I do not know the name of the method to supply.